# left join on a key if there is no match then join on a different right key to get value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two spark dataframes, say df_core & df_dict:

There are more cols in df_core but it has nothing to do with the question here

**df_core:**

```
id
1_ghi
2_mno
3_xyz
4_abc
```

**df_dict:**

```
id_1      id_2      cost
1_ghi     1_ghi     12
2_mno     2_rst     86
3_def     3_xyz     105
```

I want to get the value from df_dict.cost by joining the 2 dfs.

Scenario: join on df_core.id == df_dict.id_1

If there is a no match for df_core.id for the foreign key df_dict.id_1 (for above example: **3_xyz**) then, the join should happen on df_dict.id_2

I am able to achieve the join for the first key but have not sure about how to achieve the scenario

```py
final_df = df_core.alias("df_core_alias").join(df_dict, df_core.id== df_dict.id_1, 'left').select('df_core_alias.*', df_dict.cost)
```

The solution need not be a dataframe operation. I can create Temp Views out of the dataframes & then run SQL on it if that's easy and/or optimized.

I also have a SQL solution in-mind (not tested):

```
SELECT
    core.id,
    dict.cost
FROM
    df_core core LEFT JOIN df_dict dict
    ON core.id = dict.id_1
    OR core.id = dict.id_2
```

**Expected df:**

```
id       cost
1_ghi    12
2_mno    86
3_xyz    105
4_abc
```

Well the project plan is too big to add in the comment so I've to question here

below is the spark plan for **isin**:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) Project [region_type#26, COST#13, CORE_SECTOR_VALUE#21, CORE_ID#22]
+- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, LeftOuter, CORE_ID#22 IN (DICT_ID_1#10,DICT_ID_2#11)
   :- *(1) Project [CORE_SECTOR_VALUE#21, CORE_ID#22, region_type#26]
   :  +- *(1) Filter ((((isnotnull(response_value#23) && isnotnull(error_code#19L)) && (error_code#19L = 0)) && NOT (response_value#23 =  )) && NOT response_value#23 IN (N.A.,N.D.,N.S.))
   :     +- *(1) FileScan parquet [ERROR_CODE#19L,CORE_SECTOR_VALUE#21,CORE_ID#22,RESPONSE_VALUE#23,source_system#24,fee_type#25,region_type#26,run_date#27] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/C:/Users/XXXXXX/datafiles/outfile/..., PartitionCount: 14, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(run_date#27), (run_date#27 = 20190905)], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(RESPONSE_VALUE), IsNotNull(ERROR_CODE), EqualTo(ERROR_CODE,0), Not(EqualTo(RESPONSE_VA..., ReadSchema: struct<ERROR_CODE:bigint,CORE_SECTOR_VALUE:string,CORE_ID:string,RESPONSE_VALUE:string>
   +- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
      +- *(2) FileScan csv [DICT_ID_1#10,DICT_ID_2#11,COST#13] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/C:/Users/XXXXXX/datafiles/client..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<DICT_ID_1:string,DICT_ID_2:string,COST:string>
```

The Filter in *BroadcastNestedLoopJoin* is coming from previous *df_core* transformations but as we know spark's lazy-evaluation, we're seeing it here in the project plan

Moreover, I just realized that the final_df.show() works fine for any solution I use. But what's taking infinite time to process is the next transformation that I'm doing over the final_df which is my actual **expected_df**. Here's my next transformation:

```py
expected_df = spark.sql("select region_type, cost, core_sector_value, count(core_id) from final_df_view group by region_type, cost, core_sector_value order by region_type, cost, core_sector_value")
```

& here's the plan for the expected_df:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(5) Sort [region_type#26 ASC NULLS FIRST, cost#13 ASC NULLS FIRST, core_sector_value#21 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
+- Exchange rangepartitioning(region_type#26 ASC NULLS FIRST, cost#13 ASC NULLS FIRST, core_sector_value#21 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200)
   +- *(4) HashAggregate(keys=[region_type#26, cost#13, core_sector_value#21], functions=[count(core_id#22)])
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(region_type#26, cost#13, core_sector_value#21, 200)
         +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[region_type#26, cost#13, core_sector_value#21], functions=[partial_count(core_id#22)])
            +- *(3) Project [region_type#26, COST#13, CORE_SECTOR_VALUE#21, CORE_ID#22]
               +- BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, LeftOuter, CORE_ID#22 IN (DICT_ID_1#10,DICT_ID_2#11)
                  :- *(1) Project [CORE_SECTOR_VALUE#21, CORE_ID#22, region_type#26]
                  :  +- *(1) Filter ((((isnotnull(response_value#23) && isnotnull(error_code#19L)) && (error_code#19L = 0)) && NOT (response_value#23 =  )) && NOT response_value#23 IN (N.A.,N.D.,N.S.))
                  :     +- *(1) FileScan parquet [ERROR_CODE#19L,CORE_SECTOR_VALUE#21,CORE_ID#22,RESPONSE_VALUE#23,source_system#24,fee_type#25,region_type#26,run_date#27] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/C:/Users/XXXXXX/datafiles/outfile/..., PartitionCount: 14, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(run_date#27), (run_date#27 = 20190905)], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(RESPONSE_VALUE), IsNotNull(ERROR_CODE), EqualTo(ERROR_CODE,0), Not(EqualTo(RESPONSE_VA..., ReadSchema: struct<ERROR_CODE:bigint,CORE_SECTOR_VALUE:string,CORE_ID:string,RESPONSE_VALUE:string>
                  +- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
                     +- *(2) FileScan csv [DICT_ID_1#10,DICT_ID_2#11,COST#13] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/C:/Users/XXXXXX/datafiles/client..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<DICT_ID_1:string,DICT_ID_2:string,COST:string>
```

Seeing the plan, I think that the transformations are getting too heavy for in-memory on spark local. Is it best practice to perform so many different step transformations or should I try to come up with a single query that would encompass all the business logic?

Additionally, could you please direct to any resource for understanding the Spark Plans we get using explain() function? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `in` `left_outer` operation:

```
# Final DF will have all columns from df1 and df2
final_df = df1.join(df2, df1.id.isin(df2.id_1, df2.id_2), 'left_outer')
final_df.show()

+-----+-----+-----+----+
|   id| id_1| id_2|cost|
+-----+-----+-----+----+
|1_ghi|1_ghi|1_ghi|  12|
|2_mno|2_mno|2_rst|  86|
|3_xyz|3_def|3_xyz| 105|
|4_abc| null| null|null|
+-----+-----+-----+----+

# Select the required columns like id, cost etc. 
final_df = df1.join(df2, df1.id.isin(df2.id_1, df2.id_2), 'left_outer').select('id','cost')

final_df.show()
+-----+----+
|   id|cost|
+-----+----+
|1_ghi|  12|
|2_mno|  86|
|3_xyz| 105|
|4_abc|null|
+-----+----+
```

Comment: There are more cols in **df1** that I would like to select in the final_df & I also only want to get the **df2.cost** attribute from df2.

Plus, I have updated the scenario to have 4th row in the 1st df that is expected in the final_df!

Comment: @KrunalPatel : Check the first `show()`, it will select all columns from `df1` and `df2`. In second gave `select`, in that you can give required columns

Comment: @KrunalPatel this answer should give better performance than the other one.

Comment: @pault I have 13million rows x 4 cols dataframe. When I run both the solutions in local spark, the **isin** processes forever while the **join** process completes in a finite time. Additionally, the **sql join** solution I mentioned in the question also takes forever to process when given action statement like: show, count, write. Not sure, why the dataframe join would work just fine & sql join on Temp Views wouldn't!

Comment: @KrunalPatel : Yes, this happens sometime if join is going in `BroadcastNestedLoopJoin`. Could you please give this info **1** Do you have `null` in `df_dict.id_*` columns. **2** What is data count for  `df_core` and `df_dict` respectively. **3** Give result of `final_df.explain()`

Comment: 1. None of the join key cols have nulls

2. **df_core:** 13252550 & **df_dict:** 37503

3. I'll post in the new comment to avoid cluttering

Comment: @SMaZ I have added a new answer in the blog for your 3rd question, since this comment has word limit

Comment: @SMaZ please look for the 3rd question's answer updated in the question above

Answer (score 2):

You can join twice and use coalesce

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

final_df = df_core\
.join(df_dict.select(F.col("id_1"), F.col("cost").alias("cost_1")), df_core.id== df_dict.id_1, 'left')\
.join(df_dict.select(F.col("id_2"), F.col("cost").alias("cost_2")), df_core.id== df_dict.id_2, 'left')\
.select(*[F.col(c) for c in df_core.columns], F.coalesce(F.col("cost_1"), F.col("cost_2")))
```

Comment: Throws an error: **NameError: name 'F' is not defined**

I actually didn't understand what that F was & so just copy-paste-&-ran the code as it is!

Comment: Plus, I have updated the scenario to have 4th row in the 1st df that is expected in the final_df!

Comment: @KrunalPatel : ***F*** is `import pyspark.sql.functions as F`

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks!

P.S. I added the import statement in your code & also corrected the coalesce spelling